# Does uniswap have ONE liquidity pool per pair?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap

I'm trying to understand whether Uniswap has one liquidity pool per pair, or multiple liquidity pools per pair, each with slightly differing ratios? Of course the ratios couldn't differ significantly, not more than fees I guess. Or is that nonsense and there's a **single** address per ERC2-pair on Uniswap?

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you are referring to Uniswap V2, or Uniswap V3. In uniswap V2, there was one pair contract per erc20 pair. In uniswap V3, there can be multiple pools for each asset pair, defined at a concrete number by the fee tiers (https://docs.uniswap.org/concepts/protocol/fees).

You can also have different pool contracts from uniswap forks and other dexes. But in V3, there can be up to one pool contract per pair/fee tier combination. A pool doesn't have to exist at each fee tier for a pair, but it CAN if someone initializes it.